# FB.ui not popping up on iOS browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am setting up Facebook's Share Dialog for a website that is done in React. It seems to be working everywhere except on iOS browser (chrome).

I know that iOS are more strict with permissions. I'm not sure how to debug this.

Anyone knows possible causes of this?

Answer (score 0):

the fix for me was to use `display:dialog` for iOS instead of `display:popup`